# MySQL Table Create

Tags: mysql

Following up to see if there is a way, know this might be simple for you guys:

I need to create a table with 5 columns where columns(CostPrice) and columns(SellPrice) need to add a value into columns(Difference) in MySQL. In the example let's say I have items I wish to load and upon selling them I want that Difference calculated in the database not through a view because I'd like to reference that "Difference" value in another table when I'll at a later stage be doing a view.

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
itemAdd/itemName/costPrice/sellPrice/difference
2019-08-22/Table/100/150/50

CREATE TABLE Results (
 itemAdd Timestamp,
 itemName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 costPrice int(11) NOT NULL,
 sellPrice int(11) NOT NULL,
 (costPrice - sellPrice) as 'difference'
)
```

Reason why I want to do this through table create is because I'd update the costPrice and sellPrice of the items and would like to keep track of how the difference changed, but at the same time I'd like to reference the difference column from another table so that value shouldn't stay statically the same. Hope this makes sense. . .

Comment: I think you want a `Trigger` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) to apply after updates to take care of the calculation for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set up insert/update triggers, you can determine the difference any time there is a change.

(live sandbox example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8DVeXFdsrEBwHg168GZU2o/22)

Update your table to define the difference column.

```
CREATE TABLE Results (
 itemAdd Timestamp,
 itemName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 costPrice int(11) NOT NULL,
 sellPrice int(11) NOT NULL,
 difference int(11) NOT NULL
);
```

Then define triggers to handle the insert/updates:

```
-- handle inserts
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trg_insert_price_diff
  BEFORE INSERT ON Results
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.difference = NEW.sellPrice - NEW.costPrice;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

-- handle updates
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trg_update_price_diff
  BEFORE UPDATE ON Results
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.difference = NEW.sellPrice - NEW.costPrice;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```